# DataGridView selects, but won't update or delete

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Here's the situation.

I had a database in Access that I migrated to SQL Server. From Visual Studio 2012 (C#), I created a Data Connection with it, which is named "stanleylabs\sqlexpress.teccartHoraire.dbo". I have many tables and queries and such. I then created several DataGridViews. For example, I created a DataGridView using the table that has a list of teachers, with their first names and last names. The GridView was created. I changed the columns so they would have real sentences instead of variables as their names and I checked "Activate selection", "Activate modification", "Activate deletion" (bear in mind, I'm using a french version of Visual Studio 2012, so these options might not be named exactly like that). I haven't put in any code as of yet.

Despite having checked all those options, the DataGridView, while seeming allowing me to delete rows and add data in the tables, doesn't save them. When I execute, I'm able to add or delete or modify, but say I leave the application or simply the window, what I did doesn't update in the database. Could someone help me out with this? I searched solutions but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to explicitly update/delete the records on a specific event. When adding a data source to a database, Visual Studio creates an event handler for FormLoad event and adds a line of code that loads all records in the table from the database, similar to this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'yourDataSet.SalesOrderHeader' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.salesOrderHeaderTableAdapter.Fill(this.yourDataSet.SalesOrderHeader);
    }
```

You can see this code by pressing F7 while you edit the form.

What you will need to do is attach to some event, let's say FormClosing and update the table that is bound to the DataGridView:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.salesOrderHeaderTableAdapter.Update(this.yourDataSet.SalesOrderHeader);
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it still won't update my DataGridView...


private void modificationProf_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
 this.listeProfesseursTableAdapter1.Update(this.teccartHoraireDataSet.ListeProfesseurs);
}